Extracting records in a range in excel
Hi I have an Excel table with about 7k records.
I want to extract specific records in to a new table that have a date range of >=date1 and <=date2 The main table has a date field
I was trying to use Filter function but this will only extract records with a specific date, and there are too many dates in the extract range to use multiple Filters.
Any ideas please
Filter function but it only works for a specific date and not a range

Should be like this : =FILTER(Array,(RangeofDates>=Date1)*(RangeofDates<=Date2),""). Also please post some sample data that is copiable as text using Markdown_Table_Generator with the expected output.

You can use match() with a range of dates as well, have a look on here - there are many q&a with examples.

Why not use Data, From Table/Range button for this?

Hi thanks for the responses. I don’t understand (RangeofDates<=Date1)* (RangeofDates<=Date2)

Sorry new to this. Is RangeorDates a function? I don’t have it if it is. I am using a Mac

Hi Thanks even we dont understand from your OP, there is no sample data posted. Post some sample data, with the expected output. Sorry never used a MAC, always sticked to Windows.
